# Spring data JPA save updating parent entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Student.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Student")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Student implements Serializable {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Long id;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "studentId", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   private List<Subject> subjectList = new ArrayList<>();

   public void addSubject(Subject subject) {
     subjectList.add(subject);
     subject.setStudentId(this);
   }

   @Column(name = "firstName")
   private String firstName;

   @Column(name = "lastName")
   private String lastName;

}
```

Subject.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Subject")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Subject implements Serializable {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Long id;

   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name="studentId", nullable = false)
   private Student studentId;

   @Column(name = "subjectName")
   private String subjectName;

   @Column(name = "subjectCode")
   private int subjectCode;

}
```

SubjectRepository.java

```
@Repository
public interface SubjectRepository extends JpaRepository<Subject, Long> {


}
```

As shown in the code structure above, I have 2 entities (Student, Subject) and a repository class (SubjectRepository).  When i try to save into the Subject table, somehow the student name "Thomas" from the Student table gets updated as well in the database. I would like to only insert into Subject table without having any values from the Student table getting updated. Need some help on this. Thanks!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    @Autowired protected SubjectRepository subjectRepository;

    Student student = new Student();
    student.setFirstName("Thomas");

    Subject subject = new Subject();
    subject.setSubjectName("Chemistry");
    subject.setSubjectCode(12345);

    student.addSubject(subject)

    subjectRepository.save(subject)

}
```

Comment: Maybe you don't have any student in your base... ?

Comment: @Zorglube Forgot to mention that I already have a student row in my postgres database. Let's say the first name currently stored in Student table is "Vince". When i ran the insertSubject query, the first name gets updated to "Thomas" eventhough my query was just inserting into subject table.

Comment: Why on earth would you go to the trouble of using an ORM and then write SQL queries to insert data???????

Comment: @AlanHay I could use some advice on a better way to insert/update data

Comment: How do you expect to insert a `subject`, which has a mandatory `student` reference, without inserting the student first?

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to only insert into Subject table without having any values from the Student table getting updated

You can achieve this with following code :

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="studentId", nullable = false, updatable = false)
private Student studentId;
```

Comment: I just tried adding the **updatable = false** but the firstName in student table is still getting updated. @MaxExplode

Answer (score 0):

When using Spring JPA I would suggest using the JpaRepository API. You just need to pass in your entity, and it should save as desired.

Ex:
subjectRepository.save(subject);

Comment: I have tried doing this way but the student name from Student table still gets updated.

Answer (score 0):

You have try this

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
@JoinColumn(name="studentId", nullable = false, updatable = false)
private Student studentId;
```

Answer (score 0):

@MaxExplode You have to use cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH then other details will not update. but if you are try to set updateStudent.setfirstNamr(student.getFirstName()); and then save parent object then i will update. otherwise it will not update.